# How not cache an ASP.NET user control?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I'm using OutputCache in my page that has a user control, but I don't want to cache this specific user control because it's related to a user login (if I access the page, I see the page as if I were authenticated with another user).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally I use the VaryByCustom attribute to give logged in and logged out users different cached page views:

```
<%@ OutputCache VaryByCustom="IsLoggedIn" Duration="30" VaryByParam="*" %>
```

then in global.asax you put

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context,
    string arg)
{
    if (arg == "IsLoggedIn")
    {

        if (context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return "Logged in: " + context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Not Logged In";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
    }

}
```

I am just going to throw this out there. How about the substitution control?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228212.aspx

According to msdn website:

> The Substitution control lets you
>   create areas on the page that can be
>   updated dynamically and then
>   integrated into a cached page. ...
>   The Substitution control offers a
>   simplified solution to partial page
>   caching for pages where the majority
>   of the content is cached. You can
>   output-cache the entire page, and then
>   use Substitution controls to specify
>   the parts of the page that are exempt
>   from caching.

I have never used the substituion control personally, but I just happened to look it up the other day, and it sounded like it can somehow inject updated content into an otherwise cached page output.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache a page and you can cache a user control, but you can't cache a page except for a user control. When the user control runs the entire page has to run. You have to make the output cache for the page recognise the different users.

You can use `VaryByHeader="Cookie"` to cache the page for each set of cookies if the user identity is stored in a cookie. You can use `VaryByCustom="SomeString"` and implement a check for `SomeString` to do your own check for user identity in the `GetVaryByCustomString` method in `Global.asax`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a cache filter : http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2008/03/28/asp-net-mvc-action-filter-caching-and-compression.aspx

Check inside this filter if the user is logged or not.